# c# receive udp broadcast packets with xml content (windows 7)

Tags: c#, xml, sockets, udp

I want to receive udp packages in a c# program. the contents of several packages combined, are a XML Status Log. Which repeats after one status log is complete. See image below. I am using [this UDP Broadcast example](https://gist.github.com/zmilojko/5055246) to get the packages, with port 53181 (see picture).
But the program doesn't receive anything. Any ideas? How can I work with the received packages to get the XML data?

[image: Wireshark Screen]

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? If so, please mark it as the answer. If not. Elaborate on what you need.

Comment: Sorry, but I had no time to test your code. Thanks btw. I hope I will able to test it next week.

Comment: Mh, I am fairly new to c# programming. What is the reason for using an interface? Is it possible for you to complete the example in the way to print received data to the command line? That would help me to get the idea how to handle your code. Thanks

Comment: The purpose of the interface is to enable reuse. You can then have the receiver in a dll file while you reuse. Then you make a new class that inherits from the interface, and pass an instance of that object into the constructor of the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general purpose receiver I made in class

```
public class UdpBroadcastReceiver
{
    private IBroadcastInterpreter _interpreter;
    private volatile bool _shouldReceive = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Will listen on all ports for udp broadcasts - Will handle input with interpreter
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="interpreter"></param>
    public UdpBroadcastReceiver(IBroadcastInterpreter interpreter)
    {
        _interpreter = interpreter;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Will listen for a broadcast indefinetly. Will lock up your program.
    /// Use Task.Run to start listening. Then you can use StopListening to break the loop.
    /// </summary>
    public void ListenForBroadcast(int port)
    {
        using (UdpClient client = new UdpClient(port))
        {
            IPEndPoint senderEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            while (_shouldReceive)
            {
                byte[] receiveBuffer = client.Receive(ref senderEndPoint); // execution will stop and wait for data.
                _interpreter?.HandleBroadcast(receiveBuffer);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Breaks the while loop in ListenForBroadcast
    /// </summary>
    public void StopListening()
    {
        _shouldReceive = false;
    }
}
```

The interface

```
public interface IBroadcastInterpreter
{
    void HandleBroadcast(byte[] input);
}
```

An example implementation could be:

```
class WriteToConsole : IBroadcastInterpreter
{
    public void HandleBroadcast(byte[] input)
    {
        string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(input);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

This is a UDP broadcaster I made, to broadcast time.

```
class UdpBroadcaster
{

    private int _port;
    private bool shouldRun = true;

    public UdpBroadcaster(int port)
    {
        _port = port;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        shouldRun = false;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Entered start method");
        Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("Started task");
                    IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, _port);

                    using (UdpClient client = new UdpClient())
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Entered using statement");
                        client.EnableBroadcast = true;
                        while(shouldRun)
                        {
                            Trace.TraceInformation("Started while loop");
                            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString(new CultureInfo("da-dk")));
                            client.Send(data, data.Length, serverEndPoint);
                            Trace.TraceInformation("waiting 5 seconds");
                            Thread.Sleep(5 * 1000);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

Create an instance of the WriteToConsole class, and pass it into the constructor of the broadcast receiver. Then any time a broadcast is received, it will use the implementation of the interface to do an action. In this case, as per your request - it will just write to the console.